# Can't set value to float value

Tags: objective-c, macos

When i setting width and height value to NSTextField floatValue my customView disappear only works with numbers any ideas why?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

NSRect f = self.frame;
f.size.width = [EnterTextWidth floatValue];
f.size.height = [EnterTextHeight floatValue];
self.frame = f;
```

this one works fine:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

NSRect f = self.frame;
f.size.width = 640;
f.size.height = 480;
self.frame = f;
```

Comment: What does `EnterTextWidth` contain?

Comment: this is NSTextField it contains numbers which i enter

Comment: Are you **sure** they are numbers?  Please single-step using `lldb`.

Comment: yes i'm sure because both textfields have set value to 640 and 480 when app starts and i was using those text field in other methods and it works fine just in -awakeFromNib method it don't work.

Comment: I think you'll find that the `NSTextField` isn't initialized properly at that point in time.  Please verify with `lldb`; set a breakpoint and see what state `EnterTextWidth` is in.

Comment: yes you are right the textfields are not initialized by the time -awakefromnib is called any ideas how to set value before -awakeFromNib is called?

Comment: Erm, I think you mean after?

Comment: hmm i can't set anything before method -awakeFromNib do i?

Comment: You can, but why would you want to.  It's just been deserialised when `awakeFromNib` is called.

Comment: the problem is that i need to set my customView frame size with textfield value maybe i should use self.frame in other method any ideas where?

Comment: I've just posted an answer; have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling your code in `viewDidMoveToWindow`:

```
- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow {

    NSRect f = self.frame;
    f.size.width = [EnterTextWidth floatValue];
    f.size.height = [EnterTextHeight floatValue];
    self.frame = f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be caused by the device's locale. Try using ',' instead of '.' or vice versa as a decimal separator when writing the number in the textfields. (probably the returned value from floatValue is 0 because it cannot parse the contained number)

Comment: EnterTextWidth and EnterTextHeight has value set when the app starts so i don't think that is the problem

Comment: where did you find those values? have you tried putting some integer values?

Comment: and i'm not really imagine where you are suggesting to use ',' instead of '.'

Comment: I was talking about the decimal separators since we talk about floats. Another assumption is that the textfields are not initialised by the time awakeFromNib is called.

Comment: yes you are right the textfields are not initialized by the time -awakefromnib is called any ideas how to set value before -awakeFromNib is called?

Comment: try to setFrame to your view at a later time of its lifecycle. Or post another thread to start with delay let's say 10ms. In that thread you might need to execute the setFrame on mainThread.